# How would you alphabetize words with out using array and only strings?

Tags: java, if-statement, alphabetized

Thins is what i have so far. but i need to alphabetize all four word without using arrays and only using strings with if and else statement.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dictionary
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String word1, word2, word3, word4;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter Four Words: ");
        word1 = scan.next();
        word2 = scan.next();
        word3 = scan.next();
        word4 = scan.next();

        int compare = word1.compareTo(word2);

        if (compare < 0)
        {System.out.println(word1 + " " + word2);}
    else if (compare > 0)
        {System.out.println(word2 + " " + word1);}           
    }
}
```

Comment: You need more compares and if statements.  The rest you should be able to work out.

Comment: To understand this: what is keeping you from using a sorted List or an Array?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a reasonable foundation - you're comparing the strings properly and everything. To make tracking things easier, though, I'd make a `StringBuilder` for holding your sorted string before you start the comparisons and add words to it using `append()` after you've done all the necessary comparisons for a given word.

Follow what you have to completion, though - the key is that if you can't use a collection of any kind, you'll just have to compare each string to all the other strings. You might want to nest some additional if/elses inside what you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can also work with a List of Strings and sort it:

```
List<String> listOfWords = new LinkedList<String>();
listOfWords.add(word1);
listOfWords.add(word2);
listOfWords.add(word3);
listOfWords.add(word4);

Collections.sort(listOfWords, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How to do this using what Java offers you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final PriorityQueue<String> words = new PriorityQueue<String>();
  final Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter Four Words: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    words.add(scan.next());
  }

  while(words.isEmpty() == false) {
    System.out.println(words.poll());
  }
}
```

Not sure though if this answers your question?